# Regex to Select All Text in String Before Substring

Tags: regex, string

I have a column in my dataset that contains strings of text, similar to the following:

Campaign 225 - Facebook - CampaignName.(ThankYou) **4-225_CampaignName**

Google Ad - Franchise: Service.(ThankYou) **1-G-Fran_Service**

Campaign 225 - Google - I: CampaignName: AdGroupName.(ThankYou) **3-G-225_PT_WFH**

I want to select all text before the bolded text in each line.

I tried the following with no luck: /^(.*?)(ThankYou)/

I'm trying to do this in Java, but this is not in my wheelhouse, obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all up to the last space. It works by using the greedy quantifier.

```
.+(?=[ ]\S)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly on the first try. Thank you much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
~.+\(\w+\)~
```

Ask me if you don't understand the symbols.

Comment: what does `~.+\(\w+\)~` mean